# RecyclerView ItemOnClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

sorry for the inconvenience, but this is my first time trying this. I've been trying on doing this app which it has a recyclerView which I intent it to open a chrome page. The thing is, I'm not able to implement the itemOnClickListener despite having tried a lot of videos. Could you point out where is my mistake?

My Adapter:

```
package com.example.practica1.adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.example.practica1.R
import com.example.practica1.data.Video

class MainAdapter(private val context: Context, private val videos: List<Video>,
                  val listener: MyOnClickListener
): RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cartoon, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val video = videos[position]
        holder.title.text = video.data.short_title
        holder.serieTitle.text = video.data.show.title
        holder.durationTitle.text = video.data.video.duration + " seg"
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(video.data.imagepath)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .override(400, 400)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.imagePrev)

    }

    override fun getItemCount() = videos.size

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        val title: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoTitle)
        val serieTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.serieTitle)
        val durationTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.durationTitle)
        val imagePrev: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photoPreview)

        init{
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                val position = adapterPosition
                listener.onClick(position)
            }
        }

    }

    interface MyOnClickListener{
        fun onClick(position: Int)
    }
}
```

The fragment in which I tried to implement the method (The toast message doesn't appear)

```
package com.example.practica1.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.util.Log.d
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.practica1.R
import com.example.practica1.adapter.MainAdapter
import com.example.practica1.data.ApiInterface
import com.example.practica1.data.Video
import com.example.practica1.databinding.FragmentMenuBinding
import com.haerul.bottomfluxdialog.BottomFluxDialog
import com.haerul.bottomfluxdialog.BottomFluxDialog.OnInputListener
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class MenuFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentMenuBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        _binding = FragmentMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.cartoonnetwork.com.co")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val api = retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
        showProgress()
        api.fetchAllVideos().enqueue(object : Callback<List<Video>> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Video>>, response: Response<List<Video>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    d("daniel", "onResponse ${response.body()!![0].id}")
                    if (response.body()!!.size > 0) {
                        showData(response.body()!!)
                        getResult(true, "Sucess")
                    } else
                        getResult(false, response.message())

                    hideProgress()
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Video>>, t: Throwable) {
                d("daniel", "onFailure")
                getResult(false, "Request Timeout. Please Try Again!")
                hideProgress()
            }

        })

        binding.search.setOnClickListener { v -> showDialog(v) }
    }

    fun showData(videos: List<Video>){
        val test: RecyclerView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_viewMenu)
        test.apply{
            adapter = MainAdapter(context, videos, object: MainAdapter.MyOnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(position: Int) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            })
        }
    }

    fun showProgress(){
        binding.swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(true)
        binding.emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        binding.shimmer.startShimmer()
        binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        binding.recyclerViewMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    }

     fun hideProgress(){
        binding.swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false)
        binding.shimmer.stopShimmer()
        binding.shimmer.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        binding.recyclerViewMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }

    fun getResult(status: Boolean, message: String){
        if(!status) {
            binding.emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            binding.textEmptyErr.setText(message)
        }
        else
            binding.emptyView.setVisibility((View.GONE))
    }

    private fun showDialog(view: View){
        BottomFluxDialog.inputDialog(requireActivity())
            .setTextTitle("Input Title")
            .setTextMessage("This is an input message")
            .setRightButtonText("SUBMIT")
            .setInputListener(object : OnInputListener {
                override fun onSubmitInput(text: String?) {
                    val bundle = Bundle()
                    bundle.putString("search", text)
                    Navigation.findNavController(view)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_menuFragment_to_listFragment, bundle)
                }

                override fun onCancelInput() {}

            })

            .show()
    }


}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is showing in the recycler view and you are getting crash on item click than

```
 replace this toast link :-                     
 Toast.makeText(requireContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

with this :-

```
Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

or if your video list is not visible in recycler view than you need to implement layout manager in recycler view you can add it on xml or in code also.